# Create a view using collection view in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

I am trying to create a view similar to the attached image below. there is a variable sized width. I have marked text as black as there is a copyright issue.

Can anyone please look into the same and put some code so that it can help me somewhere.

Do I need to implement Custom Collection View Layout?

Please help me.
[image: CollectionView]

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/uicollectionviewleftalignedlayout
This is left aligned but can satisfy you requirements

Comment: https://github.com/njdehoog/NHBalancedFlowLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is response to your comment you need to add 3 extra lines of code in SGSStaggeredFlowLayout

```
NSArray* arr = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

// THIS CODE SEPARATES INTO ROWS
NSMutableArray* rows = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray* currentRow = nil;
NSInteger currentIndex = 0;
BOOL nextIsNewRow = YES;
for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* atts in arr) {
    if (nextIsNewRow) {
        nextIsNewRow = NO;
        if (currentRow) {
            [rows addObject:currentRow];
        }
        currentRow = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    if (arr.count > currentIndex+1) {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* nextAtts = arr[currentIndex+1];
        if (nextAtts.frame.origin.y > atts.frame.origin.y) {
            nextIsNewRow = YES;
        }
    }

    [currentRow addObject:atts];
    currentIndex++;
}
if (![rows containsObject:currentRow]) {
    [rows addObject:currentRow];
}
```

It works like charm :)

Comment: Thanks @Zahid...It works! Though I have not yet tested it on device. But It seems it will work. It is true that this fixes our problem. 

I have a question that during scroll the size is correct then why it makes a gap in between. Is that a bug from Apple?

Comment: No there is nothing wrong with Apple. Actually in `SGSStaggeredFlowLayout` it was analysing all cells for visible rows but every time last row was not analysed `array`. Thats why it was creating gap with every 13th row. I just checked if last row was not present in analysed rows then added it manually.

Comment: Thank you. You are a life savier..!!

Answer (score 1):

You can set size for every item by impelmenting

UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol, and calculate item width using even/odd formula.

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
 sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionView.collectionViewLayout;

    NSInteger itemsPerRow = 0;
    NSInteger contentSizeWidth = 0;
    NSInteger num = indexPath.row;
    if (num % 2)
    {// odd
        itemsPerRow = 2;
    }
    else {
    // even
        itemsPerRow = 3;
    }

    contentSizeWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width-   (flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing*(itemsPerRow-1))-flowLayout.sectionInset.left-flowLayout.sectionInset.right;

    return CGSizeMake(contentSizeWidth/itemsPerRow, 100);
}
```

Comment: Okay, but the issue I am facing is there can be variable number of items in every row. The size of the item depends upon the width of the text. I have implemented a code but the collection view is justified and there is a big space in between the items if there are 2 items in row and they are getting sticked one on left and second on right, and if there are 3 then they have a different sized margins. 

I want that wherever there is an extra space it should accomodate to the item size.

Comment: You can only set minimum item spacing in layouts. But you can make item size big enough to fit in width by implementing above delegate protocol. All you have to do is to calculate number of items per row and then calculate width for each item depending on text size that fits in width.

Comment: The problem is how to calculate how many items will be there in one row. It can be 2, 3 or 4. In the above delegate method, there comes the indexPath for the current item so I cannot calculate the size of the next item appearing.

Comment: Implement this method and check for max items which can fit in provided width  - (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath


After you get number expand you can expand them using above delegate to fill free spacing

Comment: Where do i need to override this function? In ViewController or InheritedCollectionView?

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to do this without any framework, you need to develop your own algroithm to calculate the width of each cell.

first, you need to calculate the width of text plus margin maybe border as well.

Second, calculate how many items are gonna be placed in given row. try to add 3 togther , if the total width excess the uicollection width, it means the third text should go to the next cell. if it is less than the collection width,it means you can add try to the 4th text.

third, caculate the width of each cell in each line base on how many cells are gonna placed on that line and their own width.

changing the uicollectionview width should not be diffculty since collectionviewcells are darw from left to right then top to bottom.